# Protocol error: Unknown transport

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This my rout

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection<EchoConneaction>(name: "ChatService",
     url: "/Chat"
     );
```

and this is my  PersistentConnection class
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

```
namespace SignalRPersistentConntection
{
    public class EchoConneaction:PersistentConnection
    {

    }
}
```

i get this url:

```
http://localhost:29115/chat
```

and then i get this error

> Protocol error: Unknown transport.

What is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests that you are connecting to the correct url. It would help to know how exactly you are creating the connection and invoking functions on the client/server.

Comment: Please explain exactly what can i do

Comment: Please have a look at the following page for creating connections and invoking methods: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Persistent-Connections.   Also, ensure that you have the latest version of SignalR from NuGet.